# How to convert floats into compound fractions with specific denominators?

Tags: fractions

I need to convert floats into numbers that resemble measurements from a ruler. For example: 3.75 needs to be converted into 3 and 3/4. However, this is harder than it would seem at first, because I need to keep the denominator in a form that is easily translated into a ruler measurement by a human. Essentially, the denominator should only be powers of 2, up to 16. I don't want a fraction like 3/5 because 5'ths aren't marked on a ruler. I have figured out how to limit the denominator from going above 16, but I can't figure out how to keep the denominator a power of 2.

Answers in python or c++ is preferred.

Comment: You could make an array of all values of 16ths and compare them to the decimal portion. an example array would be [0.0625,0.125, 0.1875, 0.25, 0.3125, 0.375, 0.4375, 0.5, 0.5625, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.75, 0.8125, 0.875 , 0.9375, 1] and you could compare the value to one of these and map them to a string array ["1/16", "1/8", "3/16", etc]

Comment: @Jhecht That's a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

- extract integer part, so you have fraction part less than 1.
- find nearest 16th of fraction: multiply by 16 and round to nearest integer. Have some policy to break ties (e.g. round to even). I believe this step can't introduce floating point arithmetic error because you are multiplying by a power of 2.
- reduce n/16 to lowest terms (cancel out common multiples of 2). I guess you need to compute the greatest common divisor. In Python that's `fractions.gcd`, dunno about C++.

Comment: This is probably the best root to go; I also wouldn't know how to do it in C++. Hopefully the OP would be able to convert it.

Comment: I don't need c++, python is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did what Jhecht said because it seemed easy to do with python dictionary.